# Memcached does not save generated data

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I got the following code which should save the query data to the Memcached if called and store it there for 600ms. But every time i load the page the `$response` is empty and the var_dump says MISS. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? The Memcached Server is on port 11211 as `ps aux | grep memcached` tells me.

```
$memcache = new Memcached();
$memcache->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
$response = $memcache->get("test");
var_dump($response);
if ($response) {
    var_dump('HIT');
    $result = $response;
} else {
   var_dump('MISS');
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE bla BETWEEN "'.esc_sql($start).'" AND "'.esc_sql($end).'" ORDER BY datumbekanntgabe ASC';

   $result = $this->mydb->get_results($sql);
   $memcache->set("test", $result, 0, 600);
}
return $result;
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the 600ms and see if that works?

Comment: yes, i set it to 5000, same problem

Comment: Can you check your `$memcache->set` parameters as I'm not sure what the `0` is for?

Comment: @NigelRen Compression or not

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: also we have zero idea what `$this->mydb->get_results($sql);` actually does or returns. If you are using Non-Vanilla PHP please add the code for you function/methods

Comment: OK - that isn't on the manual page - http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php which is why I was confused.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it returns an array with 1498 entries.

Comment: @NigelRen it is if you switch to german ;) http://php.net/manual/de/memcache.set.php

Comment: Can you try removing the `0` in your `set()` call as this seems to be for memcache and not memcached - or I'm just going mad :-/

Comment: @NigelRen Thats odd it is [on this page of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly but that's the memcache page not memcacheD

Comment: THIS IS IT! Thanks @NigelRen :) The third parameter is false documented in the german manual. Now it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though it was using 0 as the timeout, in the call...

```
$memcache->set("test", $result, 0, 600);
```

In [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php), the third parameter - 0 is a `flag` used for compression, whilst the fourth is the timeout, in [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) though this flag isn't present, so the call should be

```
$memcache->set("test", $result, 600);
```